# How to search Japanese character in string with PHP?

Tags: php

I have 3 strings like this:

```php
$str_1 = '「ハッスルの日」開催について';
$str_2 = 'Today is monday';
$str_3 = '(167スルの日日)';
```

I have an input box for user. If the string contains the text user input, it export that string to a CSV file. Eg - input: Today - $str_2 will be export to a new CSV.

Right now I have 2 problems:

1. If user input the Japanese bracket「 or Japanese characters, my program can't find it. I read these strings from other text file so I don't know should I encode user input or I need to encode the string. I tried both ways but it still not work out for me.
2. When I echo the Japanese characters to browser, it display ok, but when I export to CSV, it display like this: Ã§ÂµÂ„Ã§Â¹Â”Ã¥ÂÂ. What should I do to get it export correctly?

Comment: What code do you use to search for Japanese characters? What do you mean encode? What is the current character encoding you use?

Comment: `When I echo the Japanese characters to browser, it display ok, but when I export to CSV, it display like this: Ã§ÂµÂ„Ã§Â¹Â”Ã¥ÂÂ. What should I do to get it export correctly` Where does it display that? It might be exported correctly but maybe the tool that's reading the file doesn't support the character set you're using.

Answer (score 1):

We would likely use a regular expression here to detect our Japanese chars and we can start with:

```
([\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}「」]+)
```

We can simply add any other chars that we wish, to this char class:

```
[\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}「」]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ja6xh/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/([\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}「」]+)/mu';
$str = '「ハッスルの日」開催について
Today is monday
167スルの日日';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "「ハッスルの日」開催について"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "「ハッスルの日」開催について"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "スルの日日"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "スルの日日"
  }
}
```

We can also use Japanese unicodes, listed in the reference, to save/retrieve our data.

#### Reference

[Regular Expressions for Japanese Text](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/)